# Error with MDX expression

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following expression MDX :

```
isnull([Measures].[Available Hours],0)
```

After processing cube I got the following error in reporting :

> No appropriate overload function was found for the stored procedure
>   .The parameters are incorrect .MdxScript Execution of the managed
>   stored procedure isnull failed with the following error :Microsoft
>   AnalysisServices AdomdServer AdomdException

How to resolve the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isnull` is not an `mdx` function.

To test for `null` in `mdx` try using `iif`

```
 iif(  
  [Measures].[Available Hours] = 0,
  0,
  [Measures].[Available Hours]
 )
```

It looks a little strange as we look for 0 and then if it is 0 change it to 0!!

But here is an example:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 2] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = 0
     ,0
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 2]
  } ON 0
 ,
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS
  * 
    [Product].[Category].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is what happens:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Alternative by @MarcPolizzi does the same thing and his code is more compact:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 2] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = 0
     ,0
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 3] AS 
    CoalesceEmpty
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,0
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 2]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 3]
  } ON 0
 ,
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS
  * 
    [Product].[Category].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [CoalesceEmpty](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/CoalesceEmpty.php) function to replace null/empty values. To replace them with a 0 value you can do the following:

```
CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[Available Hours], 0)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Which is quicker `CoalesceEmpty( ...)` or `IIF(x=0,0,x)` ? I know that neither is recommended as they both get rid of null values, which is not good for sparse block mode calculations: but if forced to use one or the other which is quicker?

Comment: Sorry no idea for ssas; for icCube should be similar.